# file type differences for griffon when using IntelliJ

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, griffon

Why IntelliJ recognizes groovy files for Controller and Model as groovy class, but for View - as groovy script?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Griffon Views are scripts by default. IDEA is doing the right thing here.

Comment: How about Models and Controllers? Aren't we using groovy scripts there?

Comment: No, we're not. Look closely to the contents of Models and Controllers, you'll see they define classes whereas the View does not.

Comment: Groovy is the default language of choice when creating a Griffon application. Groovy supports both classes and scripts as top level definitions within a file. You can choose a different language for implementing any MVC members, see http://griffon.codehaus.org/guide/latest/guide/tips.html#nonGroovyArtifacts